# How do I Link specfic columns and checkboxes in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to link specific columns and their checkboxes. I am new to excel and VBA so it is tricky.
I want for example Columns A,C,F...
Any help is much appreciated!

I tried this code. Works fine but obviously selects all checkboxes, where I only need some specific columns.

`````
'Update by Extendoffice
Dim xCB
Dim xCChar
i = 2
xCChar = "B"
For Each xCB In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
If xCB.Value = 1 Then
    Cells(i, xCChar).Value = True
Else
    Cells(i, xCChar).Value = False
End If
xCB.LinkedCell = Cells(i, xCChar).Address
i = i + 1
Next xCB
End Sub````
`````

Comment: Why don't you just link the checkbox via [format control](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/insert-checkbox-excel/) menu? In VBA you can set it with something like `ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box " & i).OLEFormat.Object.LinkedCell = Cells(i, xCChar).Address`.

Comment: I appreciate your input. I  am working with about 100 checkboxes and was looking for a quicker way to do it than to manually link each of them via format control.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Didn't pay enouth attention. You might check the `Left` attribute of the given checkbox and verify if they falls within the `Left` attribute of the desired column.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a first draft:

```
Sub Macro1()
    
    Dim xCB
    Dim xCChar
    Dim RngColumn As Range
    
    i = 2
    xCChar = "D"
    Set RngColumn = Range("C:C")
    
    For Each xCB In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        
        If xCB.Left >= RngColumn.Left And xCB.Left < RngColumn.Offset(0, 1).Left Then
            
            xCB.LinkedCell = Cells(i, xCChar).Address
            i = i + 1
            
        End If
        
    Next xCB
    
End Sub
```